# Send data to Symfony2 controller with Ajax Post

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

If someone plays a YouTube video I want to send this information to a Symfony Controller. But somehow the controller receives nothing.

The Ajax Post

```
 // Check if video is playing (works)
  var myPlayerState;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        alert('playing');

         $.ajax({
              url: "{{ path('dbe_user_add_experience') }}",
              type: "POST",
              data: { "data" : 'test' },
              success: function(data) { 
                 alert (data);
              },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
              {
                alert('Error: ' +  errorThrown);
              }
           });
    }
    myPlayerState = event.data;
  }
```

The Routing

```
<route id="dbe_user_add_experience" pattern="/getexperience">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Level:getExperience</default>
</route>
```

The Controller

```
  public function getExperienceAction(){
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $data = $request->request->get('data');
        var_dump($data);
        die;


        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        return $response;

        //$this->addExperience(5);
  }
```

Comment: One thing is that you are using `POST`/`->request` and then checking the `GET`/`->query` part of the request.

Comment: okay, I fixed that. but I think somehow it's not sending the information at all. I checked with firebug > Networkanalysis and there is no POST method visible after the click.

Comment: Hey, is it sending the data in Json format?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$data = $request->query->get('data');
```

Use

```
$data = $request->get('data');
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed that part. But somehow I still don't see a POST method in the firebug networkanalysis.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors? is ``alert`` executed? is url properly parsed by twig?

Comment: Yes the alert is executed. How can I check if the url is properly parsed? I'm not sure if the ajax post is executed at all? I get one error message in the console: TypeError: $ is undefined

Comment: Try to use ``getexperience`` path hardcoded instead of ``path expression`` or check javascript code at your browser side, check javascript source if url is properly set

Comment: If you have $ is undefined it means that you don't have jQuery loaded, which means your ajax call can't be executed

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong property to get POST data.

To get GET data :

```
$request->query->get('data');
```

To get POST data :

```
$request->request->get('data');
```

From http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: 
Ajax was in the noconflict modus. Meaning I had to change  `$.ajax({` to `jQuery.ajax({`.